# How to add current date in filename in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to unload data from snowflakes to GCS, for that I'm using snowflakepython connector and python script. In the below python script in the file name 'LH_TBL_FIRST20200908' if the script runs today then the name will be same, if the script runs tomorrow then the file name should be 'LH_TBL_FIRST20200909' similarly if it runs day after then 'LH_TBL_FIRST202009010'.

Also please tell me if the code has any mistakes in it. Code is below

```
    import snowflake.connector
    
    # Gets the version
    ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user='*****',
        password='*******',
        account='********',
        warehouse='*******',
        database='********',
        schema='********'
        )
    cs = ctx.cursor()
    
    sql = "copy into @unload_gcs/LH_TBL_FIRST20200908.csv.gz
     from ( select * from TEST_BASE.LH_TBL_FIRST )
     file_format = 
     ( type=csv compression='gzip' 
     FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
     field_optionally_enclosed_by='"'
     NULL_IF=()
     EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE
     ) 
     single = fals
     e max_file_size=5300000000
     header = false;"
    cur.execute(sql)
    
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please don't tell us to hurry, we don't owe you anything. Please take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the ethics around here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to fill in (part of) your filename. Python has the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module to handle dates and times.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
myFileName = f'LH_TBL_FIRST{date}.csv.gz'

print(myFileName)
>>> LH_TBL_FIRST20200908.csv.gz
```

As for errors in your code:
you declare your cursor as `ctx.cursor()` and further along you just use `cur.execute(...)` and `cur.close(...)`. These won't work. Run your code to find the errors and fix them.

**Edit suggested by @Lysergic:**

If your python version is too old, you could use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
myFileName = 'LH_TBL_FIRST{0}.csv.gz'.format(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime


class FileNameWithDateTime(object):
    def __init__(self, fileNameAppender, fileExtension="txt"):
        self.fileNameAppender = fileNameAppender
        self.fileExtension = fileExtension
   
    def appendCurrentDateTimeInFileName(self,filePath):
        currentTime = self.fileNameAppender
        print(currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        filePath+=currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        filePath+="."+self.fileExtension
        try:
            with open(filePath, "a") as fwrite1:
                fwrite1.write(filePath)    
                
        except OSError as oserr:
                print("Error while writing ",oserr)
```

Answer (score -1):

I take the following approach

```
#defining what time/date related values your variable will contain
date_id = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Write the output file.

```
#Creating the filename 
with open(date_id + "_" + "LH_TBL.csv.gz" 'w') as gzip:
```

output: YYYY/MM/DD _ filename

```
20200908_filename
```